# How to unite rows or columns of Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have grid container. Grid has cells. I need unite some cells in the grid. How can achive it?[image]

The above image shows where I want to add cells.

Comment: so u mean u need to merge column 3 and 4 ? or what ? cant understand ... and what grid is it ? data grid or normal grid

Comment: Use the `Grid.ColumnSpan` property.

Comment: Yes, i want to merge these cells.

Comment: @Clemens How i can achive in xaml?

Comment: Set it on the element that is supposed to span multiple columns, just like you set `Grid.Column`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to merge all cells in individual rows you can use colunnSpan.. something like this

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"></Button>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot merge the cells but you can have the item in a cell span multiple adjacent cells.

```
<TextBox Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
```

This will allow the text box to expand to the cell below the current cell.

Similarly there is a ColSpan property to stretch to other columns.

Comment: @Muds - I am not entirely sure I understand that. There is no merging; an element can span multiple cells.Also the image in the OP shows merging rows, not columns

Comment: yea I second your approach saying - if you need to merge rows use row span, if you need to merge column use column span..